# How to modify SQL Server Error Message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have started a SQL Server locally on my computer. Now I am trying to find a way to modify error messages I get in SSMS.

Comment: You cannot modify the system messages and there's no need to. You can add a new message with `sp_addmessage`, but that's not very useful either, unless you plan on localization. If you need to produce a custom error, you can use `RAISERROR` or `THROW` in a trigger, but I'm pretty sure the column truncation check comes before a trigger, so that wouldn't work. In the end, if you don't like this particular error, don't use SSMS to edit your tables, but a custom front-end that can check these things.

Comment: The text for the error message itself can be found with `select * from sys.messages where message_id = 8152`, but changing it is not an option. It's not allowed and, even if it was, imagine the utter confusion that would result from changing every single instance of "string or binary would be truncated" to "name is too long"! The message is ambiguous enough as it is. If you want, vote on [the issue to improve the error message](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32908417-binary-or-string-data-would-be-truncated-error), which is currently the #1 suggestion.

Comment: Adding the problem column to the generic 8152 message has been a long-time SQL Server feature request. Fortunately, [improvements are planned](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32908417-binary-or-string-data-would-be-truncated-error) so we should see relief in an upcoming versions of SQL Server and SQL Azure Database. Regardless, your best approach is to use matching column lengths to avoid the error entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do a TRY-CATCH.  Something like the following:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #tmp(TestCol varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('test')

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('testtesttesttesttesttest')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @nErrorNum INT;

    SELECT  @nErrorNum = ERROR_NUMBER()

    IF @nErrorNum = 8152
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('String is too long',10,1);
    END
    ELSE
       THROW

END CATCH
```